# Create dictionary entry with key, value for each Div javascript

Tags: javascript, flask

```
<div id="divholder">
  {%for i in volcanoinfo%}
    <div class="volcdiv">
      <p id="volcanoname" style="display: none;">{{ i['name'] }}</p>
      <p id="volcanolat" style="display: none;">{{ i['vlat'] }}</p>
      <p id="volcanolon" style="display: none;">{{ i['vlng'] }}</p>
    </div>
  {%endfor%}
</div>
```

Firstly, the divs are produced as above using a json file
I am then looking to produce a dictionary where it contains Name, latitude and longitude for each div.

I have tried running a for loop in a dictionary but dont really know what I'm doing.
Is it possible to create this dictionary?
I have an array created using

```
  var div = document.getElementById('divholder');
  var volcdiv = div.getElementsByTagName('p')
  var divs = div.getElementsByTagName('div');
  var divArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
    divArray.push(volcdiv[i].innerHTML);
    console.log(divArray)
  }
```

So I know it is possible to retrieve all the data. Is there a way to now form this dictionary?
Cheers

Comment: make it object with keys name, lat, lng and push the object into divArray

Comment: @Ravi How do I go about making the object?

Comment: I've managed to create a dictionary using '''  var dict = {
  Volcname: volcdiv[0],
  Latitude: volcdiv[1],
  Longitude: volcdiv[2],
};'''
It doesnt seem to work within a loop though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to loop through the divs and get each value using query selector and push the result as an object to the result array

```js
  var div = document.getElementById('divholder');

  var divs = div.getElementsByClassName('volcdiv');
  var divArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 1) {
    console.log(divs[i])
    var volcanoname = divs[i].querySelector('[id="volcanoname"]').innerHTML
    var volcanolat = divs[i].querySelector('[id="volcanolat"]').innerHTML
    var volcanolon = divs[i].querySelector('[id="volcanolon"]').innerHTML
    divArray.push({"volcanoname":volcanoname, "volcanolat": volcanolat, "volcanolon": volcanolon });
  }
  document.getElementById("result").value = JSON.stringify(divArray);
```

```html
<div id="divholder">
    <div class="volcdiv">
      <p id="volcanoname" >1</p>
      <p id="volcanolat" >11</p>
      <p id="volcanolon" >111</p>
    </div>
        <div class="volcdiv">
      <p id="volcanoname" >2</p>
      <p id="volcanolat" >22</p>
      <p id="volcanolon" >222</p>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="result"/>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uwdczrh0/2/

Comment: This seems to be close, however the array shows each output with the tag styling like below
'\n          <p class="volcanoname" style="display: none;">Amukta</p>\n          <p class="volcanolat" style="display: none;">52.50000</p>\n          <p class="volcanolon" style="display: none;">-171.25200</p>\n        '
Is there a way to get just the text?

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: For the above example:
("volcname": "Amukta", "volcanolat":"52.50000","volcanolon":"-171.25200")
for each of the volcdiv's created

Comment: This is the current output format of my answer. [{"volcanoname":"1","volcanolat":"11","volcanolon":"111"},{"volcanoname":"2","volcanolat":"22","volcanolon":"222"}]

Comment: I see, I was using it in console to get my weird result.
Is there a way to call a specific value? As in wanting to call the 3rd volcanoes name and no other values

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working with 
''''document.getElementById("result").innerHTML  = JSON.stringify(divArray[4].volcanoname);''''

Comment: take it directly from the divArray array